# GridView paging in UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have an UpdatePanel and a GridView within it. I have a problem with paging: when I press Next button, grdUsers_PageIndexChanging() is not called, so the page stays 1, and if previously I changed selection in ddlPageSize, now it goes back to the initial selection.
Also, if I am on the first page, the Previous button is not disabled, and pressing it causes Out Of Range error.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlUsers" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Always" >
    <ContentTemplate>

        <div style="height:400px; width:1500px; overflow:auto;">

        <asp:GridView ID="grdUsers" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" ShowHeader="false" ShowFooter="true" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="largegridview largegridview_td" 
            Width="1480px" Height="100%" PageSize="100" DataKeyNames="ID" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="false" 
                onpageindexchanging="grdUsers_PageIndexChanging" 
                onrowdatabound="grdUsers_RowDataBound">
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alternatingrowstyle" />

                <Columns>
                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Name" SortExpression="Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LastName">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>                        
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FirstName">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Email") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>                        

                </Columns>

                <PagerStyle CssClass="pagerstyle" />
                <PagerTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Show rows:" />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPageSize" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPageSize_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="20" />
                        <asp:ListItem Value="50" />
                        <asp:ListItem Value="100" />
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    &nbsp;
                    Page 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtGoToPage" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                        OnTextChanged="GoToPage_TextChanged" CssClass="gotopage" />
                    of
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTotalNumberOfPages" runat="server" />
                    &nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="btnPrev" runat="server" CommandName="Page" 
                        ToolTip="Previous Page" CommandArgument="Prev" CssClass="previous" />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" CommandName="Page" ToolTip="Next Page" 
                        CommandArgument="Next" CssClass="next" />                  
                </PagerTemplate>                      
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: can you show  this event code grdUsers_PageIndexChanging()

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are doing anything wrong; it may not actually fire the PageIndexChanged event, it probably fires the RowCommand event.  Attach to the ItemCommand event and that will receive the event.

HTH.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't see ItemCommand event. Could you please explain?

Comment: Err may be its RowCommand, got the wrong event name.  RowCommand fires for every command clicked; it's a one-size-fits-all event, so it will also fire for paging, etc. too.  Some events are only handled through RowCommand, and it will handle your custom commands.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, I tested the code, and grdUsers_PageIndexChanging() is called on mine.

Answer (score 0):

Dear Friend 
their is in build paging in the gridview if you want your own paging style then you have to implement your own paging through PageDataSource Class.

[Click to view code](http://codeasp.net/articles/asp-net/140/implement-paging-in-repeater-or-datalist-control)

this link provide you how to implement the paging in the Datalist and Repeater through same way you will implement  the paging in grid view .
Then no pageindex change event will fired in the gridview.